# Petrol Pump establishment algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

There is one locality given, that is represented by a matrix and every entry indicates the number of cars in that area. Our task is to place a petrol pump at one entry in the matrix, so that the block we choose that gives the minimum travel cost.

I found a solution that takes `O(n^4)` time in which we compute the whole process for every entry.

Can you tell me any other good approach for this question?

Comment: How is the cost defined?

Comment: move one path is equal to one unit cost

Comment: Do you mean that the cost from the block *x* to the location of the pump is the number of the cars in *x* multiplied by the [manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from *x* to the pump?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? ... if so, you've just got three bright people to do your homework for you...

Comment: On the plus side, if so then jhamb will understand the solution thoroughly once he/she has read the answers to the question. As long as the homework is not for meaningful credit, I doubt this is a problem.

Comment: AKE its not a homework..I hate homework type things and all. This is passion to become a coder one day, may above than peter, mimino, Oleg. :)
Actually I am prepared for an Interview for google, as I am shortlisted in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll expand Rupert's answer with a practical example (i.e. how to compute what he calls the median row and column).

As he said, **you can find the optimal row and the optimal column for the pump separaterly**. How?

Let us consider the following instance of the problem:

```
3 2 7
1 8 9 
7 2 2
```

- **First, we find the optimal row for the pump**

We start adding all the rows of the matrix

```
3 2 7 -> 12
1 8 9 -> 18
7 2 2 -> 11
```

now if we place the pump in the first row, the **total vertical cost** is

```
11*2 + 18*1 + 12*0 = 30
```

since the 11 cars in row 3 have to travel for 2 vertical units, the 18 cars in row 2 have to travel for 1 vertical unit, and the cars in row 1 do not have to travel in vertical. We have to compute the total vertical travel cost for all the rows.

```
pump in 1st row -> cost 30 = 11*2 + 18*1 + 12*0
pump in 2nd row -> cost 23 = 11*1 + 18*0 + 12*1
pump in 3rd row -> cost 42 = 11*0 + 18*1 + 12*2
```

so **the optimal row for the pump is the 2nd**.

We computed this in O(n^2), since we did O(n^2) sums when the summed all the *n* cars in the *n* rows, and we did O(n^2) sums and multiplication when we computed the total vertical cost for each possible row for the pump.

- **Now we find the optimal column for the pump**

We sum the cars in each column:

```
3  2  7
1  8  9 
7  2  2
_______
11 12 18
```

now:

```
pump in 1st col -> cost 48 = 11*0 + 12*1 + 18*2
pump in 2nd col -> cost 29 = 11*1 + 12*0 + 18*1
pump in 3rd col -> cost 34 = 11*2 + 12*1 + 18*0
```

so **the optimal column for the pump is the 2nd**.

**In O(n^2) steps, we found that we have to place the pump in [2][2]**.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably much less obscure to read than my original! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood your question correctly, so your cost function is as Haile describes in his/her comment, there's an easy solution since you can reduce to a one-dimensional problem.

Note that in the Manhattan metric, the distance in columns that the cars must traverse is just summed with the distance in rows, so we can minimise them separately.

So we've reduced the problem to one dimension. To work out what was going on, I had to switch this to a continuous problem. So suppose that I have a density function, p(x), (let's say it's continuous with compact support, so that the maths works). Then the cost function is given by

[image: \int p(x) |x-x0|]

Splitting this into two halves to get rid of the mod sign and differentiating (this is where you need to assume p(x) is well behaved), you get

[image: \int_-\infty^x_0 p(x) - \int_{x_0}^\infty p(x)]

Now, the optimal position for x0 is going to be the one that makes this derivative zero. But notice that this is the median of the distribution.

For the discrete setting, which was the original question, the same arguments work. Basically you can take a discrete derivative, which is E(k+1)-E(k). If you write a[n] for the number of cars at position n, then the cost function splits up as

[image: E(k) = \sum_{n<k} a_n(k-n) + \sum_{n>k} a_n(n-k)]

Assuming I haven't made a stupid mistake, the discrete derivative comes out as

[image: E(k+1)-E(k) = \sum_{n<k+1} a_n - \sum_{n>k+1} a_n]

so the solution will be at the median again (rounded either way if you end up at a half-integer). To see why this is true, note that if k is a large negative number, this derivative is definitely negative (so increasing k by 1 will decrease the cost). Now, as k increases, the derivative slowly increases. At some point, it will become positive for the first time. This happens as soon as k+1 is larger than the median. After that, it will stay positive, so the correct k to choose is the largest k less than or equal to the median.

The original question was in two dimensions, so you need to run this twice, once for each axis.

Comment: I think so: Suppose we are in a 1d situation with cars spaced on the real line. Then the total distance travelled is the sum over cars of the distance between pump and that car. I'm pretty certain that this sum is minimised at the mean position of the cars.

Comment: (Er, that comment was in response to one that seems to have gotten deleted: it's meant to justify why taking the mean is the correct thing to do on each axis)

Comment: sorry for deleting my comment, i wanted to double-check. anyway, imagine that there are just two populated blocks, one with 9 and the other with 10 cars - the optimal location is always in the cell with the 10 cars, although the mean location may vary

Comment: Suppose block 0 had 9 cars and block 1 had 10 cars. Then the mean is going to be 10/19 > 0.5, so rounding gives you 1 as required. If the blocks aren't adjacent, the best solution will be probably be somewhere between them.

Comment: If there are 10 cars in (0,0) and 9 cars in (10,0) the pump in (5,0) will have a cost of 10*5 + 9*5 = 95 while the pump in (0,0) will have a cost of 9*10 = 90 < 95.

Comment: @Haile: You're completely right. Sorry, I need to think about this for a minute.

Comment: the more i think about it, the more it seems as though brute-forcing is the only way (every solution i come up with seems to be equivalent). still, O(n^2) per side of matrix isn't bad. @RupertSwarbrick, kudos for catching the invariant.

Comment: I think that you can find the optimal row in O(n^3), and then the optimal column in O(n^3), giving an overall O(n^3) algorithm.

Comment: @Haile, to find the optimal column, you need to sum the rows into an n element vector and scalar multiply it by each of the n vectors of the form (0..n-1),(1,0,1..n-2),(2,1,0..n-3), finding the least product => O(n^2)

Comment: So it was the median, not the mean. Sorry for being dopey.

Comment: @staafl: Hmm, thinking about it, any solution must be at least O(n^2), if n is the width/height of the matrix. After all, there are n^2 numbers that one has to look at! However notice that there are n multiplications your solution has to do for each dot product, and n dot products, so I think your algorithm is cubic.

Comment: (And you can find the median row and column in quadratic time, of course)

Comment: @RupertSwarbrick I want one expert advise from you, please guide me. I  normally saw the coding questions is easily solved by using mathematics. Can you please tell me a book or reference from where I improve my mathematics logics used in programming. Thanks in advance. As you use pretty well mathematics in your answer thats why I am asking this question.